# Open source os for dlink dsl-2640u hw: c2

Tags: router, opensource-projects

Can anybody tell me which wireless router firmware projects already supports dsl-2640u hw: c2? OpenWRT works as a router, but the WiFi does not.

However I'd like to be able to use the wireless adapter. Any suggestions on which projects might support this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're out of luck with that hardware. It doesn't have support within the OpenWRT project for it:

- http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dsl-2640u-bru-c

I found no other opensource firmware project that support it either. I went through each of the project's router databases:

- [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index)
- [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato)

Additionally I went through the larger projects and none supported this device.

- [List of wireless router firmware projects - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wireless_router_firmware_projects)